# Shared composite primary key mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-primary-key, hibernate-annotations

I have this problem and I was not able to solve it, I need help.
I can't imagine how can I map a composite shared pk, below is an example:

```
Table X:
a_id(pk)(fk),
b_id(pk)(fk)

Table Y:
b_id(pk)(fk),
c_id(pk)(fk)
```

now I have a many-to-many relationship between table X and table Y represented in a table Z.

```
Table Z:
a_id(pk)(fk),
b_id(pk)(fk),
c_id(pk)(fk)
```

How can I map table Z using Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I meant table Z, I updated the question

Comment: table A have many-to-many relationship with B and table B have many-to-many relationship with C?